# getConstraintId returns zero with soft bodies

Tags: python, game-engine, constraints

I want to create some constraints in BGE with phyton (between a soft body and a dynamic object) and then remove them after a while. I tried this code to save constraint's id:

```
import bge

p = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects["Plane"].getPhysicsId()

o = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner

o["c"] = bge.constraints.createConstraint(o.getPhysicsId(), p, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0).getConstraintId()
```

the constraint created and all of parameters seems to be correct but **getConstraintId always returns zero** and I can't understand why?

Comment: also [here](http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/GameModule/ClassKX_ConstraintWrapper_1.html) mentioned that it will returns zero **if there isn't a constraint ID** but i can't figure out why there shouldn't be a constraint ID?

Comment: the code also works well when I change the soft body (plane) to a rigid body. only when it is soft, there isn't a constraint id!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an experience I understand that Blender's Game Engine can't create constraints on **Soft Bodies** dynamically by bge codes. Actually it creates the constraints but you don't have any access to them.